# display block is not working in my project

Tags: html, css

I'm having the issue with my HTML & CSS at this moment that they go inline when using 'display: block;'.

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
  background-color: #343434;
}

.button .active {
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.button ion-icon {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 2px;
  font-size: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #343434;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div slot="bottom" class="navbar">
  <div class="button">
    <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
    <label>Home</label>
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <ion-icon name="list-box"></ion-icon>
    <label>Agenda</label>
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
    <label>Numbers</label>
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
    <label>Settings</label>
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
    <label>Account</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone knows a quick fix for this. I don't understand why its not working. (Neither working with removing float: left & overflow: hidden

Comment: You are using "float: left;"  so this is exactly what will happen, remove that and if you want to make sure that any element will "float" you can use "clear:both;"

Comment: You say "(Neither working with removing float: left", so can you tell us what you expect to happen exactly?

Comment: what exactly issue is? Its not clear with the question

Comment: as I already said, when removing the float:left nothing changes. It still doesnt work

Comment: you have to change a little thing and that is you have to just give width: 100% instead of width: 75px  in button CSS and all your problems gone.

Comment: In what way do the `.button` divs "go inline"? They are blocks; they are underneath one another and the `width` property works. What else do you expect from a block?

Answer (score 0):

if your navbar is on the left and you want them to stack in a column on top of each other use display block and a width of 100%, if your navbar is on the top and you want them in a row next to each other use display initial or inline and put all of the navbar elements in one div and a px width based on your screen.